# Couldn't find Category without an ID for a Rails E-Library Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, categories

[Complete Stack Trace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVMks.png)

I'm experiencing some problems while trying to create categories for my books Ruby on Rails project.

I have been able to create categories for the books, but each time I try to view the categories for the books, I tend to get the error :

```
**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController, 
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=10, 
app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:69:in `set_category**
```

I have tried nesting the books resources into the categories resources in the routes.rb file, but its still not working. I have also tried a lot of solutions, but none seem to work. I don't know what to do next.

**This is the routes.rb file code**

```
get 'dashboard/index'
devise_for :admins
resources :categories do
  resources :books
end
```

**This is the categories_controller.rb file code**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: %i[show index]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

def index
 @categories = Category.all
end

def show
end

def new
  @category = Category.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  @category = Category.new(category_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @category.save
    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @category.update(category_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @category.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_category
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description)
 end
end
```

**This is the books_controller.rb file code**

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
end

def show
end

def new
  @book = Book.new 
end

def edit
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end

def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  @book.category_id = params[:category_id]

respond_to do |format|
  if @book.save
    format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_book
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :description, :link, :image, :category_id, :new_category_name)
 end
end
```

**This is the _form.html.erb file for the book view**

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select Category" %>
or create one:
<%= form.text_field :new_category_name %>
```

**This is the edit.html.erb file for the book view**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-12"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">
        <h1>Editing Book</h1>
        <hr>

            <%= render 'form', book: @book %>

            <hr>
            <%= link_to 'Show Book', @book %> |
            <%= link_to 'Delete', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> |
            <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the index.html.erb file for the category view**

```
<div class="row listrow">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <div class="pb_pricing_v1 p-5 border text-center bg-white card">
      <hr>
      <h3><%= category.name %></h3> <br />
          <p class="pb_font-15"><%=h truncate(category.description, :length => 100, :omission => "" , :escape => false) %>...</p>
          <%= link_to 'View Category', category, class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-shadow-blue"  %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

How can I view my categories and books created under the categories?

Comment: can you please provide more information about the error ? like add the full stack error, so I would be sure that my answer is right

Comment: Need stack error along with processing parameters also!

Comment: And can you please show all the content of `categories_controller.rb`

Comment: either you don't have `category_id` in your parameters OR it's there but it's named `id`. If it's the latter, just use `params[:id]` in your set_category hook

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Category with 'id'=10):

app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:69:in `set_category'. I have also changed the set_category method to @category = Category.find(params[:id]) but still no luck. I cannot edit/update categories when I create them too because of this error. Don't know what to do

Comment: @Xero, @ray and @reiallenramos, the content of the `categories_controller.rb` file is fully shown upwards in the question section. I am also willing to provide more insight about the question if you need any more insight. **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController**,  **Couldn't find Category with 'id'=10**, **app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:69:in `set_category**

Comment: @PromisePreston are you sure that the category with id 10 exists in database ?

Comment: @Xero, Yes, it does, I run into issues each time I try to update the category, but I can view the category.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to the line : (in `set_category` method)

```
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

This is the line that cause your error :

```
Couldn't find Category without an ID
```

Because, I assume, that `params[:category_id]` is empty.

Comment: This is common but you cannot be sure without log!

Comment: I agree, I'm waiting some logs to complete my answer

Comment: **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Category with 'id'=10): app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:69:in set_category.**  I have also changed the `set_category` method to **@category = Category.find(params[:id])** but still no luck. I cannot edit/update categories when I create them too because of this error. Don't know what to do

Comment: @PromiseChukwuenyem check what is in your "params" (by doing `pp params` before `@category = ...`) To be sure that your params is send

Comment: @Xero, can you please explain better on how I can fix this issue, because I am a new to Ruby on Rails. All my codes are posted in the question. I would be very grateful if I can get this fixed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @PromiseChukwuenyem please edit your post and add the complete `categories_controller.rb` I'm sure it's not complete. And the complete stack error (with the information on the route called (POST http://..) When you would have done that, I will edit my post and explain you.

Comment: I have updated the `categories_controller.rb` code above with the complete code. As for the route, I only used **resources :categories** as shown in the code in the question. I have also uploaded a screenshot of the error above using **Complete Stack Trace Screenshot** as the title. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I started off the whole process again and then realized that I was calling the destroy action in the edit book page, which it didn't permit.

I simply removed the link to the destroy action from the edit book page and everything became fine.

**This is the edit.html.erb file for the book view**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-12"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">
        <h1>Editing Book</h1>
        <hr>

            <%= render 'form', book: @book %>

            <hr>
            <%= link_to 'Show Book', @book %> |
            <%= link_to 'Delete', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> |
            <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**